# How to derive the conditional posterior density in hierarchical bayesian models?

Tags: probability, bayesian, self-study, mathematical-statistics, hierarchical-bayesian

I was reading on Gelman's Bayesian Data Analysis - Chapter 5 - Hierarchical model

Suppose:
data : $y_j$ s

parameter: $\theta$

hyperparameter: $\phi$

On page 126, he mentions the analytical derivation of conditional and marginal distributions.

I understand that we can easily derive the joint posterior distribution using factorisation based on Bayes' theorem, but I don't understand how to derive the conditional posterior distribution $p(\theta|\phi ,y)$. Is there a general method to go about deriving the conditional posterior distribution? Based on Bayes' theorem perhaps?

Please explain thoroughly.

Comment: Without the book to hand it is difficult to relate it to *Gelman et al*, so I have made this a comment. Generally speaking, a full conditional is sometimes used because it's often easy to do that from a modelling point of view. That is, it's often relatively easy to specify a model in the conditional form.

Comment: I think that this question and answers would be of help:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48662/reasonable-assumption-in-bayesian-linear-regression/48682#48682